# Communicate to docker host from windows container using mounted named pipe

Tags: docker, dockerfile, virtualization, named-pipes, docker-for-windows

I cannot communicate to the Docker host from my windows container.Tested it by mounting named pipe.The named pipe is visible in my windows container, but I have not managed to successfully use the Docker Engine API.

The base image is *mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803*.

The client library used is https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet

I get timeout when I run the application in a container.
There are no errors when I run the application locally.

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine image-name`

```
var clientConfiguration = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"));
var client = clientConfiguration.CreateClient();

var images = client.Images.ListImagesAsync(new ImagesListParameters { All = true}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
foreach (var image in images)
{
    Console.WriteLine(image.ID);
}
```

I expect the communication to work by mounting named pipes.
I will be really glad if someone can point me in the right direction. :)

**Thank you in advance!**

P.S. This is my first Stack Overflow question!

Hello World(Stack Overflow)!